# Transform/Pivot a CSV

Tags: java, r, csv, matrix, pivot

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
a, b, c, d
e, f
```

I want to pivot the rows to look like a matrix. With each item in a row starting first and all the other items in the same row coming after.

```
a, b, c, d
b, c, d, a
c, d, a, b
d, a, b, c     
e, f
f, e
```

Suggestions on how to implement this in Java or in R?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method for the first row using `sapply` and subsetting:

```
vec <- letters[1:4]

sapply(1:4, function(i) vec[c(i:4, 1:i)][1:4])
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d" 
[2,] "b"  "c"  "d"  "a" 
[3,] "c"  "d"  "a"  "b" 
[4,] "d"  "a"  "b"  "c"
```

The easiest method in R is to work with lists, since the number of elements in each row is different. With a list structure, here is a nested `sapply` method:

```
myList <- list(letter[1:4], letters[5:6])
sapply(myList, function(j) {
                 sapply(1:length(j), function(i) {
                   j[c(i:length(j), 1:i)][1:length(j)]})})
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d" 
[2,] "b"  "c"  "d"  "a" 
[3,] "c"  "d"  "a"  "b" 
[4,] "d"  "a"  "b"  "c" 

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "e"  "f" 
[2,] "f"  "e"
```

Answer (score 0):

In `R`, we can loop through the rows and use `matrix` to derive the expected output

```
lst <- apply(df, 1, function(x)  {x1 <-x[nzchar(x)]
        head(matrix(x1, nrow=length(x1)+1, ncol = length(x1)),-1)})
lst
#[[1]]
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,] "a"  "b"  "c"  "d" 
#[2,] "b"  "c"  "d"  "a" 
#[3,] "c"  "d"  "a"  "b" 
#[4,] "d"  "a"  "b"  "c" 

#[[2]]
#    [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "e"  "f" 
#[2,] "f"  "e"
```

NOTE: If we have NAs instead of blanks (`''`), then `x1 <- x[!is.na(x)]` in the above code.

If we need to create a single dataset, then `rbindlist` from `data.table` can be used

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(lst, as.data.frame), fill = TRUE)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
#1:  a  b  c  d
#2:  b  c  d  a
#3:  c  d  a  b
#4:  d  a  b  c
#5:  e  f NA NA
#6:  f  e NA NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(v1 = c("a", "e"), v2 = c("b", "f"), v3 = c("c", 
""), v4 = c("d", "")), .Names = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4"),
 row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```